# If photos are retrieved from a damaged iPhone, will their quality be the same as when they were taken?

Tags: iphone, photos, damage

An iPhone XS has been subject water to both physical and heat damage, however, the photos are still accessible when connected to a computer. Can physical damage to an iPhone also affect the quality of the photos taken on it?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question several times.

Answer (score 0):

No. The storage in phones is quite durable. As long as the photos are accessible the quality should not change.

The damage would need to happen in a unique way for the quality to be affected before the accessibility is affected. The phone has to pretend to be a camera for the photos to show up and the phone can also be set to block USB access if not unlocked. It is not just a microSD card with some photos.